# Uniqueness of minimal elements in a totally ordered set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

Let $R$ be a total order on set $S$. Prove that if $S$ has a minimal element, than the minimum element is unique.

I have difficulties with proofs. I know any graph of a total order is a straight line, which clearly has a minimal element. How doI tell when something is mathematically proven?

EDIT: this is how I would prove it

Let $x, y \in S$ such that x and y are minimal. Since S is a total order $x$ and $y$ are comparable and either

case 1: one comes after the other and therefore one isn't the minimal
case 2: both are the same and $x=y$

I know this isn't a mathy argument and could use help making it more presentable.

Comment: Please read about [accepting answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: A nitpick: In general, when we are dealing with a partially-ordered set, a *minimal* element is an element which is not greater than any other elements. A *minimum* element is one which is less than all other elements. A minimum element (if any) of a partial order will always be the unique minimal element, but even a unique minimal element need not be the minimum. For example, take some $a\notin\Bbb Z,$ and define $\precsim$ on $\Bbb Z\cup\{a\}$ by $x\precsim y$ iff $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ and $x\le y.$ Then $a$ is not the minimum, but is the unique minimal element.

Comment: What is the name of the strange symbol that looks like a less than?

Comment: A "straight line" has no minimal element. Otherwise your argument is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $S$ is a partially ordered set in which is $s$ is a minimal element,  then $\forall x\in S(x\leq s\implies x=s)$.

Since $R$ is a total order and $s$ is minimal, it follows that $s$ is in fact **a** minimum.

Now to answer your question.

**Hint:** Suppose $s'\in S$ is also a minimum. Relate it do $s$ and try to conclude that $s=s'$.

---

What you wrote is good enough for an answer, but you're asking for a 'more symbolic' answer, so here it is.

**Full answer:**

As stated above, since $R$ is a partial order with a minimum element $s\in S$, then $\forall x\in S(x\leq s\implies x=s)$.

But $R$ is a total order, thus $\forall x\in S(x\leq s\lor s\leq x)$, therefore, since $s$ is minimal $\forall x\in S(x=s\lor s\leq x)$, i.e., $\forall x\in S(s\leq x)$, that is, $s$ is a minimum of $S$ with respect to the order $R$.

Now suppose $s'$ is also a minimum of $S$ with respect to $R$, then, by definition of $s'$ being a minimum, it holds that $s'\leq s$. On the other hand, $s$ is a minimum too, so $s\leq s'$. From $s'\leq s\land s\leq s'$ it follows that $s=s'$. This proves that all minimum elements are the same, that is, there is a unique minimum element.

---

It's probably good to note that the fact that $R$ is a total order is only necessary to prove that a minimum exists.

On any poset, if there is a minimum, the reasoning above proves it is unique.

Comment: Didn't you just assert the answer in your first line?

Comment: @NovaDenizen I did, I meant to write something different. I fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Ok I updated my question with new work

Comment: @Celeritas Your answer is fine. I rewrote it as requested.

Comment: I don't know the notation S(x≤s⟹x=s). why is there brackets?

Comment: @Celeritas You should read $\forall x\in S(x=s\lor s\leq x)$ as *for all* $x$ in $S$ such that $x=s$ or $s\leq x$.

Comment: Ok so that's another way to read "such that"? I already know : and | mean such that.

Comment: @Celeritas Yes, but $\colon$ and $\mid$ are used when defining sets while what I wrote is 'such that' in logic notation.

Answer (score 1):

The antisymmetric property of a total order says that if $a <= b$ and $b <= a$ then $a = b$.  How would two distinct minimal elements relate to each other?

Comment: Good question but I don't know why we should see this in "Answers" section...